# How to use chart.js drawing multiple lines from line sets with (X, Y) values?

Tags: javascript, python, chart.js

I'm not going to chart multiple lines by months as Chart.js document.
I have some data like:

line1={(X=1.1, Y=100), (X=2.1, Y=200), ... }

line2={(X=1.2, Y=110), (X=2.2, Y=210), ... }

......

I want all lines being charted on the same canvas as the below picture.
[image: Multiple lines demo, coordinates not the same as the numbers above]

I mean different lines may have different X cordinates .

Chart.js seems not support this sort of line charting(points must be aligned exactly on the fixed X listed in label list). Chart.js may like:

X = {X=1.1, X=2.1, ...}

line1={ y1, y2, y3 ... }

line2={ y'1, y'2, y'3 ...  }

All lines share the same X. This is not what I want.

I need every line have it's own X list, line1(X1 list, Y1 list), line2(X2 list, Y2 list) .....lineN(XN list, YN list)

However QT can handle this well as I expect.

If Chart.js is not best to do this work please tell me which one is good. I don't like to draw lines on canvas by raw js. Is Plotly a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [Plotly.js](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_graphics_plotly.asp) can do this.

```
<div id="myPlot" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var xValues = [50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150];
    var x2Values = [30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130];
    var yValues = [7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,14,14,15];
    var y2Values = [9,9,8,9,9,19,20,11,34,4,05];
    
    var data = [
      {x: xValues, y: yValues, mode:"lines"},
      {x: x2Values, y: y2Values, mode:"lines"}
    ];
    var layout = {title: "Plotly Chart"};

    Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
    
</script>
```

As the picture shown below, the lines don't have to use the same X list.
[image: Demo of Plotly.js]

I expects more answers to my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely do [multiple line](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html) on a chart via chart.js
Chart.js is pretty strict on its data structure format.(Also I've only heard it being used with javascript)

```
export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      type: "line" as const,
      label: "Dataset 1",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 }))
    },
    {
      type: "line" as const,
      label: "Dataset 2",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 2, 192, 1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(155, 99, 132,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 }))
    },
    {
      type: "bar" as const,
      label: "Dataset 3",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.1)",
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 }))
    }
  ]
};
```

Above you have three datasets so you have 2 lines and some bars. Than that data variable is passed to a chart.

On the react side, here is a codesanbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-multiple-dataset-r1kixh?file=/App.tsx:1747-2138

Comment: I'll spend some time to understand and try since I'm not using React. Your post give me confidence.

Comment: definitely feel free to post the code you have and/or a sandbox too!

Comment: Hi, lkura, I read your code carefully, but I found it's not what I want. Sorry I didn't express clearly. All your lines still share the same list of labels( X coordinates ). What I want is like line_1(X1, Y1), line_2(X2, Y2). Every line has its own Xs and Ys. Your code is accutually line_1(X, Y1), line_2(X, Y2), all lines are sharing the same list of X.

Comment: Can chart.js do that?